# VBA-WEB unable to authorize with httpbasic authenticator

Tags: excel, vba, rest

I am trying to use VBA-Web for submitting REST API via Excel VBA and running into issues

https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

I tried to modify this example to use HttpBasicAuthenticator but unsuccessful it says HTTP error 401. When I use Postman to submit the rest request it is fine.

https://github.com/revisohq/api-samples/tree/master/rest/excel

If I use this Url that does not need to authenticate. It works as expected

https://rest.reviso.com/customers?demo=true

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim Client As New WebClient
    Dim Request As New WebRequest
    Client.TimeoutMs = 30000 ' 30 seconds

    Client.BaseUrl = "https://postman-echo.com/basic-auth"
    'Client.BaseUrl = "https://rest.reviso.com/customers?demo=true"
    Request.Format = WebFormat.Json

    Dim Auth As New HttpBasicAuthenticator
    Auth.Setup _
    Username:="postman", _
    Password:="password"


    Dim Response As WebResponse
    Set Response = Client.Execute(Request)

    If Response.StatusCode <> Ok Then
        Sheets("Test").Range("A1") = Response.StatusDescription
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim Json As Object
    Set Json = WebHelpers.ParseJson(Response.Content)

    FillData Json

End Sub
```

Comment: Does it have to be using that tool or will another xmlhttp method be ok?

Comment: I am also confused as to the problem url. If it is with the reviso endpoint then your app needs to be configured to make prior GET request for the agreement token. That should then be supplied with secret token to interact with service.

Comment: @QHarr Yes ideally I would like to use VBA-Web. The code works without basic authentication. I'm not sure which part of my code is wrong.

Comment: The guidance seems to suggest you need to get an agreement token.

Comment: @QHarr. Yes for Reviso it needs an agreement token. I am now working with Postman https://postman-echo.com/basic-auth, it uses basic authentication. I am not able to get this work

Comment: You don't need any authentication do you for demo one - otherwise you need to token whether using postman or other method.

Comment: @QHarr do you have any hint?